# Swift: Could not cast NSCFString to NSNumber when parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift3

I have a JSON object, I need to extract a float value from this. 
The JSON looks like this:

```
{"ticker":{"base":"NLG","target":"USD","price":"0.05896390","volume":"","change":"-0.00044477"},"timestamp":1477232372,"success":true,"error":""}
```

My goal is to get the price as a float. I am able to retrieve the json and log it when not casted to a float it prints: Optional(0.05896390).

When I cast it as a float I get the warning:

> could not cast value of type `NSCFString` to `NSNumber`

```
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
 let tick = json["ticker"]!["price"]! as! Float
 print(tick)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`price` is clearly a string. In a JSON object everything between double quotes is a string even it seems to be a number.

```
if let tick = json["ticker"] as? [String:Any], let price = tick["price"] as? String {
    print(Float(tick))
}
```

Since all values are `String` you can even cast the dictionary to more specific `[String:String]`

```
if let tick = json["ticker"] as? [String:String], let price = tick["price"] {
    print(Float(tick))
}
```

Notes:

- Since you have to unwrap the optionals anyway do it safely with optional bindings.
- In Swift 3 the JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`

Comment: By the way, it's a price, therefore using `NSDecimalNumber` instead of `Float` is advisable.